# Find lines that end with "+"

Tags: grep

I am unable to form a grep regex which will find me only those lines that end with + signs. Example:

Should match - `This is a sample line +`

Should not match - `This is another with + in between` or `This is another with + in between and ends with +`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do use `$` to indicate the end of the line:

```
grep '+$' file
```

#### Example

```
$ cat a
This is a sample line +
This is another with + in between
hello

$ grep '+$' a
This is a sample line +
```

### Update

> What if I want to display lines which only has + in the end. Even if a
>   line is like this This is a line with + in bw and in the end +. I
>   don't want this line to be matched.

Then you can use `awk`:

```
awk '/\+$/ && split($0, a, "\+")==2' file
```

#### Explanation

- `/\+$/` matches lines ending with `+`.
- `split($0, a, "\+")==2` divides the string in blocks based on the `+` delimiter. The return value is the number of pieces, so `2` means that it just contains one `+`.

#### Example

```
$ cat a
This is a sample line +
This is another with + in between
Hello + and +
hello

$ awk '/\+$/ && split($0, a, "\+")==2' a
This is a sample line +
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I was doing the same thing but on a file created by Windows, I copied the file contents and created a new file and voila!

Comment: Nice to read that :) Sometimes using Windows file in UNIX can lead to strange characters. If so, you can always use the `dos2unix` command to clean them.

Comment: What if I want to display lines which only has + in the end. Even if a line is like this `This is a line with + in bw and in the end +`. I don't want this line to be matched.

Comment: See update. Also, consider not changing the requirement after posting the first question.

Answer (score 1):

Specify that the ending `+` should *not* be preceded by any other `+`, or as a regular expression:

```
grep '^[^+]*+'
```

Output when tested on the 2nd version of [fedorqui's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22147288/1331399) `a` file:

```
This is a sample line +
```