# How to use grep to print lines ending with a certain string?

Tags: linux, grep

I wanted to print all lines from a file containing "FAIL**". I don't wanted any lines with FAILED or FAILURE to be printed. How do I do this? I want to the output to go into another file.

The lines end with this string.

Comment: What does `**` means?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find lines that end with "+"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147274/find-lines-that-end-with)

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

Your command should be,

```
grep 'FAIL\*\*$' file
```

Escape the * chracter to make your grep command to work.

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
avi
la FAIL**
FAIL
foo FAIL**
bar FAIL**

$ grep 'FAIL\*\*$' file
la FAIL**
foo FAIL**
bar FAIL**
```

Comment: to get the ouput to go into another file `grep 'FAIL\*\*$' file > anotherfile`

Comment: Thanks. As it turns out the ** is in the text itself.

Comment: yep, the above `cat` displays the contents of my file.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` will also works too:

```
awk '/FAIL\*\*$/' file
```